# Server with Own Implemented Handler is not listening Continuously

Tags: go

I am trying to understand how to implement http.Handler, correctly. I wrote the barebone package code. Here is my package code

```
package app

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

//Handler is the handler function
type Handler struct {
}

func (h *Handler) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Running ServeHTTP")
    rw.Write(([]byte)("Hello"))
    return
}

//NewHandler is
func NewHandler() *Handler {
    return &Handler{}
}

//Start will start the server
func (h *Handler) Start() {
    fmt.Println("Running Start")
    http.ListenAndServe("8080", h)

}
```

I made a directory in the abovementioned package named it "examples". I made a file `main.go` and wrote this in main function(After importing the Package).

```
func main() {

    handler := app.NewHandler()

    handler.Start()
}
```

But, when I run it with `go run *.go`, The Program abrupts almost instantly after writing `Running Start` on console. Shouldn't it listen continuouly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the name of the package of the `main.go` file?

Comment: It is package main, because it will be an executable

Comment: Have you tried `:8080` instead of `8080`?

Comment: Don't ignore errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `http.ListenAndServe()` func returns error.
You could just check that by logging:

```
fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe("8000", h))
```

and you will see that in your case its returning an error causing the function to return.

All you need to do is to pass address as `:8000`

Comment: Though , not a direct answer, It lead me to solve the problem. So thank you. The error was I did not add semicolon in port. It should be ":8080" . You edited answer. I am accepting it.